# How to add unit in date_sub function of mysql using java prepared statements

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a prepared query wherein the unit part of the date needs to be passed as a parameter. Below is the code

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL ? ?)");
ps.setInt(1,timeInterval);
ps.setString(2,unit);
```

Note: `timeInterval` is an `int` variable & `unit` is a `String` variable which can be "DAY","MINUTE" and so on.
Using this final query build as

```
select DATE_SUB(1511846832475,INTERVAL 2 'DAY')
```

But when I run it the following exception is thrown.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Day')' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
```

Comment: exception message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot represent the interval unit using a placeholder.  The reason for this is that, as you have seen, binding a unit as a string will escape it with single quotes.  But it is possible to use a placeholder for the quantity, which you are already doing in your code snippet.

I can offer two workarounds.  One is that you have separate prepared statements depending on whether the interval be DAY, MINUTE, and so on.  But this might feel a bit clunky to you.  Another workaround would be to convert all your interval values into a common unit, e.g. MINUTE.  Then, just use the following single prepared statement for everything:

```
String query = "SELECT DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL ? MINUTE)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setInt(1, timeInterval);
```

Comment: A third option is to dynamically build the SQL at runtime, e.g. `query = "SELECT DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL ? " + unit + ")"`. Should only be done if `unit` is safe, i.e. known to be a valid unit keyword.

Comment: *FYI:* The reason that unit cannot be a placeholder, is that it is not a string value, but a keyword. See [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add): ***`unit` is a keyword** indicating the units in which the expression should be interpreted.*

Comment: @Andreas To your first comment, this is why I left out suggesting dynamically building the query, because it might leave things open to some sort of attack.